# Check if at least one element of a list is a contained in a list with R

Tags: r, list

I try to check if  at least there is one element of a list var2 is a contained in the list booster_word. For this I use :

```
any(var2 %in% booster_word)
```

But it is incorrect.

Example :

```
 > var2
    [[1]]
    [1] "served" "both"   "as"    

    > booster_word
     [1] "more"       "very"       "too"        "much"       "completely" "absolutely" "fully"      "totally"    "definitely" "extremely" 
    [11] "often"      "frequently" "enough"     "a lot"      "as"        
    > any(var2 %in% booster_word)
    [1] FALSE
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: `any(booster_word %in% unlist(var2))` ??

Comment: Ok thank you, it works. Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `list` to a `vector` with `[[` as it is of `length` 1.

```
 any(var2[[1]] %in% booster_word)
```

Comment: Ok , it works , thank you. @Ronak Shah gives me another solution too